# Can I modify a fragment from another one?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm trying to get to some composents of a fragment from another one like this way :

```
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header_fragement, null);

    name = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nameH);
    img = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeader);

    name.setText(infos.getString("Name"));
    img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(infos.getString("ImgUrl")));

    View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer, null);

    mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(header);
    mDrawerListView.addFooterView(footer);
```

it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom compound view instead of a Fragment.

You have a [nice tutorial there](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#tutorial_compoundcontrols) (not pasting code here because of the length)

See also the [official developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound).

You can then make your header and footer views like that:

```
HeaderView header = new HeaderView(myContext);
```